# Почему не показывается форматирование в превью вопросов?

Tags: предложение, форматирование

Почему не отображается форматирование в превью вопросов ?
Как по мне легче читалось бы, не столь монотонно.

А именно:

- Слова жирным шрифтом, чтобы выводились жирным.
- Курсив - курсивом
- Часть с кодом другим цветом, ибо при ">pre<>code<" используется доп.пространство
- Цитата другим цветом. Горчичным например.
- Тэги и ссылки, собственно остаётся как есть. Т.е та же гиперссылка.

Над списками думаю. Ну или списки выводить как есть, чтобы не трогать доп.пространство.

Так было бы ещё ясно, кто изначально задумывается о привлекательности текста.
Всё просто к тому,что приятнее читать. Автоматически мозг акцентируется на том или ином.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О каком форматировании идет речь? И почему с ним должно стать легче?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский маркдаун в списке вопросов не рендерится.

Comment: @Nofate ммм. ну впихивать маркдаун в превью из двух с 1/4 строчки - как-то глупо.

Comment: Особенно в вопросах типа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/747194/191482  ... у которого в итоге в превью будет только `Есть обработчик:`. супершедевр

Comment: Можно было бы часть с кодом выделять другим цветом.

Comment: @stackflow вам бы поработать в начале над предложением детально. Как раз внести *предложение*: что и где и как выделять и почему. А то сейчас выглядит: мне не нра, сделайте, чтоб нра.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот будет у вас в начале вопроса идти сразу кусок кода отформатированный на 50 строк, всё это в превью пихать? Превью обрезает по количеству символов (200 символов) и/или до конца предложения.

Я так понимаю, это не стали делать из-за того, что сложно реализовать превью, когда необходимость обрезать кусок текста, который обрамлён в теги.

**P.S.** я вот лично вообще редко на текст превью смотрю, обычно достаточно заголовок прочитать.

Comment: Хотя бы жирный шрифт и курсив. И я не говорю про все 50 строк, а ту часть которая выводится в превью.

Comment: @stackflow автор вопроса не знает, какая часть текста в превью войдёт.

Comment: В превью входит случайный участок написанного?

Comment: 200 символов первых.

Comment: @stackflow предлагаю вам провести исследование на данную тему. Взять? например, 10.000 вопросов и проанализировать у скольки процентов из них имеется курсив или жирный шрифт в первых 200 символах, которые отводятся на превью. Предоставить данные общественности и если он действительно на столько критичен - то внести предложение. Ну и конечно объяснить аргументированно, как это положительно скажется на отображении и на обществе